# Not set curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

Tags: node.js

When you run (in Git Bash) `https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` it says:

> sh.exe": sudo: command not found

What is the reason? And How To Fix It

Comment: Copy your error messages as text. Don't link to screenshots of them.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the reason?

You are trying to run a Linux (and other UNIX) install script, using a program to grant admin access on a Linux/etc system but are doing so on a Windows computer.

> And How To Fix It

Follow the [instructions for installing on Windows](https://npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Fancy-Windows-Install).

Comment: directory content with "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" already have  nmp.cmd and director node_modules\nmp\...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to install `npm` separately? `npm` gets installed when you install `node.js`. What happens you get when you do `which npm; npm -v`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script from Cygwin, you don't need `sudo`, as `sudo` is not present there, it is only present in *nix systems. The other thing is, that Node.js comes with `npm`, so you should install Node.js, as that is needed for `npm` and it also includes `npm`.

Comment: @R__ just install Node.js from http://nodejs.org/ and you will get *npm* and *node*.